# как лучше спарсить xml?

Tags: javascript, xml

есть [такой](https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?expire=1566330372&hl=ru&signature=3181CDC7B8FA00B755EA4C62B5F64B460E3B16F2.9CE78622F8C54A31A65169FA3C983738DC75DDCF&caps=asr&sparams=asr_langs%2Ccaps%2Cv%2Cxoaf%2Cxorp%2Cexpire&xorp=True&key=yttt1&v=_Gs34D0Bnk4&asr_langs=en%2Cde%2Cko%2Cja%2Cfr%2Cru%2Cpt%2Cnl%2Ces%2Cit&xoaf=1&kind=asr&lang=ru&fmt=srv3) xml

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<timedtext format="3">
<head>
<pen id="1" fc="#E5E5E5"/>
<pen id="2" fc="#CCCCCC"/>
<ws id="0"/>
<ws id="1" mh="2" ju="0" sd="3"/>
<wp id="0"/>
<wp id="1" ap="6" ah="20" av="100" rc="2" cc="40"/>
</head>
<body>
<w t="0" id="1" wp="1" ws="1"/>
<p t="0" d="4680" w="1">
<s ac="252">всем</s>
<s t="420" ac="252"> привет</s>
<s t="900" ac="249"> пока</s>
<s t="1230" ac="252"> я</s>
<s t="1380" ac="252"> готовлю</s>
<s t="1680" ac="252"> выпуск</s>
<s t="2220" ac="252"> про</s>
</p>
<p t="2480" d="2200" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="2490" d="4920" w="1">
<s ac="252">один</s>
<s t="419" ac="252"> день</s>
<s t="630" ac="252"> из</s>
<s t="780" ac="252"> жизни</s>
<s t="810" ac="112"> программисты</s>
<s t="1710" ac="249"> где</s>
<s t="1920" ac="252"> все</s>
</p>
<p t="4670" d="2740" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="4680" d="5010" w="1">
<s ac="252">снимаю</s>
<s t="389" ac="252"> на</s>
<s t="480" ac="252"> камеру</s>
<s t="720" ac="252"> как</s>
<s t="990" ac="252"> и</s>
<s t="1199" ac="252"> обещал</s>
<s t="2010" ac="217"> я</s>
<s t="2310" ac="252"> решил</s>
</p>
<p t="7400" d="2290" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="7410" d="4229" w="1">
<s ac="220">сделать</s>
<s t="210" ac="252"> выпуск</s>
<s t="689" ac="248"> в</s>
<s t="990" ac="252"> котором</s>
<s t="1410" ac="252"> покажу</s>
<s t="1800" ac="250"> какие</s>
</p>
<p t="9680" d="1959" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="9690" d="4770" w="1">
<s ac="227">приложил</s>
<s t="540" ac="0"> query</s>
<s t="750" ac="236"> игры</s>
<s t="1050" ac="250"> установлены</s>
<s t="1199" ac="251"> у</s>
<s t="1860" ac="252"> меня</s>
</p>
<p t="11629" d="2831" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="11639" d="5611" w="1">
<s ac="251">на</s>
<s t="271" ac="252"> телефоне</s>
<s t="571" ac="160"> и</s>
<s t="1201" ac="243"> если</s>
<s t="1651" ac="252"> кто</s>
<s t="1861" ac="229"> не</s>
<s t="1981" ac="240"> знает</s>
<s t="2401" ac="245"> то</s>
<s t="2611" ac="252"> в</s>
</p>
<p t="14450" d="2800" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="14460" d="5340" w="1">
<s ac="247">этом</s>
<s t="240" ac="252"> плане</s>
<s t="540" ac="252"> я</s>
<s t="750" ac="252"> фанат</s>
<s t="1320" ac="241"> продукции</s>
<s t="1980" ac="240"> apple</s>
<s t="2280" ac="224"> и</s>
<s t="2640" ac="244"> не</s>
</p>
<p t="17240" d="2560" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="17250" d="5130" w="1">
<s ac="238">потому</s>
<s t="420" ac="241"> что</s>
<s t="690" ac="252"> я</s>
<s t="840" ac="252"> мажор</s>
<s t="1170" ac="252"> телефоны</s>
<s t="1890" ac="252"> на</s>
<s t="2010" ac="252"> android</s>
</p>
<p t="19790" d="2590" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="19800" d="5370" w="1">
<s ac="212">мне</s>
<s t="180" ac="249"> тоже</s>
<s t="540" ac="218"> как</s>
<s t="809" ac="243"> бы</s>
<s t="840" ac="238"> нравится</s>
<s t="1440" ac="236"> просто</s>
<s t="2040" ac="246"> я</s>
<s t="2130" ac="229"> ценю</s>
</p>
<p t="22370" d="2800" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="22380" d="4380" w="1">
<s ac="216">простоту</s>
<s t="600" ac="218"> и</s>
<s t="809" ac="227"> удобность</s>
<s t="1470" ac="236"> айфонов</s>
<s t="2130" ac="147"> а</s>
<s t="2159" ac="204"> вообще</s>
<s t="2639" ac="252"> по</s>
</p>
<p t="25160" d="1600" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="25170" d="4170" w="1">
<s ac="252">большому</s>
<s t="240" ac="233"> счету</s>
<s t="630" ac="249"> мне</s>
<s t="1080" ac="221"> поесть</s>
</p>
<p t="26750" d="2590" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="26760" d="4710" w="1">
<s ac="176">такая</s>
<s t="390" ac="252"> трубка</s>
<s t="630" ac="197"> в</s>
<s t="870" ac="250"> кармане</s>
<s t="1320" ac="202"> главное</s>
<s t="2070" ac="252"> чтобы</s>
<s t="2370" ac="249"> она</s>
</p>
<p t="29330" d="2140" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="29340" d="4770" w="1">
<s ac="249">работала</s>
<s t="179" ac="200"> и</s>
<s t="779" ac="161"> таран</s>
<s t="1199" ac="227"> дело</s>
<s t="1410" ac="252"> когда</s>
<s t="1679" ac="239"> кто-то</s>
</p>
<p t="31460" d="2650" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="31470" d="5730" w="1">
<s ac="252">звонит</s>
<s t="690" ac="210"> iphone</s>
<s t="1230" ac="252"> и</s>
<s t="1260" ac="252"> если</s>
<s t="1620" ac="252"> честно</s>
<s t="1740" ac="249"> это</s>
<s t="2130" ac="247"> говно</s>
</p>
<p t="34100" d="3100" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="34110" d="5789" w="1">
<s ac="252">полное</s>
<s t="300" ac="177"> ребят</s>
<s t="1170" ac="244"> не</s>
<s t="1289" ac="250"> берите</s>
<s t="1740" ac="200"> сейчас</s>
<s t="2400" ac="220"> лето</s>
<s t="2760" ac="248"> и</s>
<s t="2879" ac="250"> на</s>
</p>
<p t="37190" d="2709" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="37200" d="4949" w="1">
<s ac="230">жаре</s>
<s t="330" ac="211"> they</s>
<s t="660" ac="198"> сми</s>
<s t="1019" ac="137"> телефоны</s>
<s t="1650" ac="252"> перегреваются</s>
<s t="2519" ac="252"> и</s>
</p>
<p t="39889" d="2260" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="39899" d="4410" w="1">
<s ac="252">начинают</s>
<s t="541" ac="215"> жёстко</s>
<s t="660" ac="232"> глючить</s>
<s t="1590" ac="206"> и</s>
<s t="1741" ac="251"> их</s>
<s t="1951" ac="233"> приходится</s>
</p>
<p t="42139" d="2170" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="42149" d="4021" w="1">
<s ac="246">выключать</s>
<s t="480" ac="249"> включать</s>
<s t="1381" ac="252"> из-за</s>
<s t="1651" ac="252"> этого</s>
<s t="2041" ac="252"> по</s>
</p>
<p t="44299" d="1871" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="44309" d="4051" w="1">
<s ac="252">несколько</s>
<s t="750" ac="252"> раз</s>
<s t="901" ac="252"> в</s>
<s t="1201" ac="252"> день</s>
</p>
<p t="46160" d="2200" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="46170" d="4350" w="1">
<s ac="227">это</s>
<s t="240" ac="252"> сильно</s>
<s t="659" ac="252"> напрягает</s>
<s t="900" ac="237"> особенно</s>
<s t="1770" ac="252"> когда</s>
<s t="1979" ac="252"> тебе</s>
</p>
<p t="48350" d="2170" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="48360" d="4410" w="1">
<s ac="252">нужно</s>
<s t="240" ac="255"> что-то</s>
<s t="719" ac="249"> быстро</s>
<s t="870" ac="249"> сделать</s>
<s t="1650" ac="252"> или</s>
<s t="1800" ac="215"> кому-то</s>
</p>
<p t="50510" d="2260" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="50520" d="4219" w="1">
<s ac="246">быстро</s>
<s t="449" ac="239"> позвонить</s>
<s t="1109" ac="233"> но</s>
<s t="1350" ac="252"> вместо</s>
<s t="1710" ac="252"> этого</s>
<s t="1830" ac="252"> ты</s>
</p>
<p t="52760" d="1979" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="52770" d="4500" w="1">
<s ac="252">вынужден</s>
<s t="600" ac="252"> страдать</s>
<s t="1050" ac="124"> подобные</s>
<s t="1559" ac="110"> хусти</s>
</p>
<p t="54729" d="2541" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="54739" d="4721" w="1">
<s ac="230">перезагрузкой</s>
<s t="1000" ac="134"> и</s>
<s t="1121" ac="252"> на</s>
<s t="1241" ac="233"> тебя</s>
<s t="1511" ac="252"> все</s>
<s t="1631" ac="252"> окружающие</s>
</p>
<p t="57260" d="2200" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="57270" d="5010" w="1">
<s ac="252">смотрят</s>
<s t="300" ac="252"> как</s>
<s t="629" ac="243"> на</s>
<s t="660" ac="247"> дал</s>
<s t="960" ac="0"> спабо</s>
<s t="1469" ac="118"> а</s>
<s t="1620" ac="209"> ты</s>
<s t="1800" ac="209"> такой</s>
</p>
<p t="59450" d="2830" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="59460" d="3360" w="1">
<s ac="252">стоишь</s>
<s t="419" ac="252"> и</s>
<s t="450" ac="251"> улыбаешься</s>
<s t="1140" ac="251"> и</s>
<s t="1439" ac="221"> типа</s>
<s t="1860" ac="212"> зато</s>
<s t="2250" ac="237"> iphone</s>
</p>
<p t="62270" d="550" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="62280" d="6900" w="1">
<s ac="223">black</s>
</p>
<p t="62810" d="6370" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="62820" d="8640" w="1">
<s ac="187">и</s>
<s t="3530" ac="242"> начнем</s>
<s t="4530" ac="205"> с</s>
<s t="4680" ac="255"> оформления</s>
<s t="4830" ac="234"> моей</s>
<s t="5700" ac="248"> трубы</s>
</p>
<p t="69170" d="2290" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="69180" d="4380" w="1">
<s ac="203">ибо</s>
<s t="180" ac="239"> всем</s>
<s t="509" ac="241"> похер</s>
<s t="780" ac="207"> чё</s>
<s t="990" ac="228"> у</s>
<s t="1110" ac="244"> меня</s>
<s t="1200" ac="237"> там</s>
<s t="1560" ac="205"> установлена</s>
</p>
<p t="71450" d="2110" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="71460" d="4470" w="1">
<s ac="247">как</s>
<s t="330" ac="242"> видите</s>
<s t="690" ac="252"> у</s>
<s t="839" ac="252"> меня</s>
<s t="960" ac="248"> самый</s>
<s t="1560" ac="208"> дешевый</s>
</p>
<p t="73550" d="2380" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="73560" d="5010" w="1">
<s ac="252">силиконовый</s>
<s t="720" ac="252"> чехол</s>
<s t="1169" ac="252"> на</s>
<s t="1320" ac="186"> которой</s>
<s t="1830" ac="248"> я</s>
<s t="1919" ac="205"> зачем-то</s>
</p>
<p t="75920" d="2650" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="75930" d="4740" w="1">
<s ac="149">приклеил</s>
<s t="570" ac="101"> стикеры</s>
<s t="1079" ac="161"> at</s>
<s t="1259" ac="235"> republic</s>
<s t="1500" ac="200"> of</s>
<s t="1979" ac="202"> геймер</s>
<s t="2520" ac="217"> с</s>
</p>
<p t="78560" d="2110" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="78570" d="4979" w="1">
<s ac="226">которые</s>
<s t="510" ac="238"> шли</s>
<s t="750" ac="250"> вместе</s>
<s t="1140" ac="239"> с</s>
<s t="1260" ac="252"> материнкой</s>
<s t="1710" ac="90"> комп</s>
<s t="2070" ac="125"> а</s>
</p>
<p t="80660" d="2889" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="80670" d="5640" w="1">
<s ac="252">когда</s>
<s t="510" ac="252"> я</s>
<s t="660" ac="255"> его</s>
<s t="870" ac="236"> собирал</s>
<s t="1559" ac="239"> и</s>
<s t="1739" ac="247"> на</s>
<s t="1949" ac="241"> самом</s>
<s t="2370" ac="247"> деле</s>
<s t="2610" ac="240"> это</s>
</p>
<p t="83539" d="2771" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="83549" d="5191" w="1">
<s ac="252">выглядит</s>
<s t="631" ac="251"> оригинально</s>
<s t="1231" ac="249"> поэтому</s>
<s t="1921" ac="252"> пусть</s>
<s t="2341" ac="252"> будет</s>
</p>
<p t="86300" d="2440" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="86310" d="4739" w="1">
<s ac="252">как</s>
<s t="390" ac="217"> говорится</s>
<s t="840" ac="252"> пока</s>
<s t="1230" ac="252"> не</s>
<s t="1410" ac="127"> отклеилось</s>
<s t="2280" ac="249"> не</s>
</p>
<p t="88730" d="2319" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="88740" d="4860" w="1">
<s ac="252">трогай</s>
<s t="629" ac="99"> ну</s>
<s t="900" ac="238"> и</s>
<s t="989" ac="200"> перейдем</s>
<s t="1440" ac="251"> пожалуй</s>
<s t="1650" ac="147"> уже</s>
<s t="2100" ac="244"> к</s>
</p>
<p t="91039" d="2561" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="91049" d="5731" w="1">
<s ac="93">внутренностям</s>
<s t="750" ac="217"> моего</s>
<s t="1171" ac="255"> айфона</s>
<s t="1741" ac="236"> ибо</s>
<s t="2070" ac="227"> тот</s>
<s t="2280" ac="248"> у</s>
<s t="2311" ac="244"> нас</s>
</p>
<p t="93590" d="3190" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="93600" d="5790" w="1">
<s ac="252">самое</s>
<s t="300" ac="251"> интересное</s>
<s t="1170" ac="107"> а</s>
<s t="1440" ac="206"> начну</s>
<s t="1860" ac="252"> я</s>
<s t="1979" ac="217"> цикл</s>
<s t="2550" ac="226"> который</s>
</p>
<p t="96770" d="2620" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="96780" d="5010" w="1">
<s ac="252">у</s>
<s t="89" ac="242"> меня</s>
<s t="269" ac="245"> установлены</s>
<s t="1080" ac="246"> и</s>
<s t="1260" ac="252"> которыми</s>
<s t="1890" ac="252"> я</s>
<s t="2070" ac="252"> убиваю</s>
</p>
<p t="99380" d="2410" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="99390" d="4619" w="1">
<s ac="252">время</s>
<s t="269" ac="252"> когда</s>
<s t="659" ac="252"> нечем</s>
<s t="1080" ac="214"> заняться</s>
<s t="1560" ac="158"> да</s>
<s t="1979" ac="252"> и</s>
<s t="2070" ac="239"> вообще</s>
</p>
<p t="101780" d="2229" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="101790" d="3899" w="1">
<s ac="252">когда</s>
<s t="329" ac="252"> ты</s>
<s t="420" ac="243"> берешь</s>
<s t="780" ac="255"> чей-то</s>
<s t="1079" ac="247"> телефон</s>
<s t="1200" ac="255"> в</s>
<s t="1829" ac="255"> руки</s>
<s t="2130" ac="249"> и</s>
</p>
<p t="103999" d="1690" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="104009" d="3811" w="1">
<s ac="160">почему-то</s>
<s t="390" ac="226"> всегда</s>
<s t="601" ac="204"> интересно</s>
<s t="1290" ac="252"> сначала</s>
</p>
<p t="105679" d="2141" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="105689" d="2881" w="1">
<s ac="252">посмотреть</s>
<s t="570" ac="252"> какие</s>
<s t="871" ac="252"> там</s>
<s t="1081" ac="248"> у</s>
<s t="1110" ac="247"> чувака</s>
<s t="1531" ac="247"> стоят</s>
</p>
<p t="107810" d="760" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="107820" d="3329" w="1">
<s ac="237">игрухи</s>
</p>
<p t="108560" d="2589" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="108570" d="5640" w="1">
<s ac="194">и</s>
<s t="60" ac="243"> первое</s>
<s t="659" ac="245"> во</s>
<s t="810" ac="251"> что</s>
<s t="1020" ac="252"> я</s>
<s t="1110" ac="252"> люблю</s>
<s t="1500" ac="201"> позалипать</s>
<s t="2280" ac="201"> это</s>
</p>
<p t="111139" d="3071" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="111149" d="5610" w="1">
<s ac="247">игра</s>
<s t="421" ac="187"> флип</s>
<s t="871" ac="0"> бегом</s>
<s t="1411" ac="104"> и</s>
<s t="1591" ac="252"> хотя</s>
<s t="1921" ac="233"> это</s>
<s t="2161" ac="204"> донатное</s>
<s t="2821" ac="237"> дно</s>
</p>
<p t="114200" d="2559" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="114210" d="5339" w="1">
<s ac="202">играть</s>
<s t="600" ac="252"> в</s>
<s t="720" ac="205"> нее</s>
<s t="839" ac="239"> все</s>
<s t="1140" ac="249"> же</s>
<s t="1290" ac="255"> можно</s>
<s t="1680" ac="239"> без</s>
<s t="2189" ac="252"> интернета</s>
</p>
<p t="116749" d="2800" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="116759" d="4921" w="1">
<s ac="244">и</s>
<s t="390" ac="248"> без</s>
<s t="720" ac="249"> покупки</s>
<s t="1110" ac="235"> чего-либо</s>
<s t="1470" ac="122"> суть</s>
<s t="2281" ac="252"> заключается</s>
</p>
<p t="119539" d="2141" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="119549" d="4350" w="1">
<s ac="252">просто</s>
<s t="481" ac="252"> в</s>
<s t="661" ac="252"> том</s>
<s t="750" ac="247"> что</s>
<s t="1081" ac="222"> ты</s>
<s t="1201" ac="75"> этапы</s>
<s t="1561" ac="207"> из</s>
<s t="1741" ac="252"> нужный</s>
</p>
<p t="121670" d="2229" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="121680" d="4280" w="1">
<s ac="252">момент</s>
<s t="299" ac="252"> чтобы</s>
<s t="570" ac="119"> сработала</s>
<s t="1049" ac="246"> гравитация</s>
<s t="1799" ac="243"> и</s>
<s t="1890" ac="252"> твоя</s>
</p>
<p t="123889" d="2071" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="123899" d="3951" w="1">
<s ac="252">пушка</s>
<s t="301" ac="252"> не</s>
<s t="601" ac="122"> упало</s>
<s t="1021" ac="252"> на</s>
<s t="1141" ac="252"> землю</s>
<s t="1320" ac="208"> как</s>
</p>
<p t="125950" d="1900" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="125960" d="4769" w="1">
<s ac="153">да</s>
<s t="30" ac="155"> дело</s>
<s t="300" ac="215"> тебе</s>
<s t="570" ac="248"> нужно</s>
<s t="930" ac="251"> умудриться</s>
<s t="1260" ac="255"> собирать</s>
</p>
<p t="127840" d="2889" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="127850" d="5640" w="1">
<s ac="205">по-трошки</s>
<s t="240" ac="219"> монетки</s>
<s t="1170" ac="238"> бустеры</s>
<s t="1799" ac="249"> и</s>
<s t="1890" ac="233"> все</s>
<s t="2070" ac="239"> такое</s>
<s t="2549" ac="236"> в</s>
</p>
<p t="130719" d="2771" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="130729" d="4651" w="1">
<s ac="238">общем</s>
<s t="271" ac="249"> разберешься</s>
<s t="931" ac="234"> как</s>
<s t="1590" ac="251"> видишь</s>
<s t="2041" ac="251"> все</s>
<s t="2071" ac="252"> очень</s>
</p>
<p t="133480" d="1900" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="133490" d="3570" w="1">
<s ac="237">просто</s>
<s t="420" ac="228"> из</s>
<s t="719" ac="252"> приятной</s>
<s t="1260" ac="252"> графикой</s>
</p>
<p t="135370" d="1690" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="135380" d="3630" w="1">
<s ac="240">именно</s>
<s t="360" ac="252"> поэтому</s>
<s t="630" ac="165"> эта</s>
<s t="1050" ac="248"> игра</s>
<s t="1200" ac="253"> все</s>
<s t="1560" ac="248"> еще</s>
</p>
<p t="137050" d="1960" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="137060" d="4020" w="1">
<s ac="238">установлено</s>
<s t="270" ac="244"> у</s>
<s t="780" ac="245"> меня</s>
<s t="1020" ac="251"> на</s>
<s t="1140" ac="252"> телефоне</s>
</p>
<p t="139000" d="2080" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="139010" d="4770" w="1">
<s ac="204">вторая</s>
<s t="660" ac="252"> игрушка</s>
<s t="930" ac="212"> в</s>
<s t="1230" ac="252"> которую</s>
<s t="1620" ac="252"> я</s>
<s t="1740" ac="252"> люблю</s>
</p>
<p t="141070" d="2710" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="141080" d="5820" w="1">
<s ac="246">поиграть</s>
<s t="450" ac="223"> очень</s>
<s t="960" ac="236"> похоже</s>
<s t="1500" ac="252"> на</s>
<s t="1650" ac="252"> первую</s>
<s t="2100" ac="252"> но</s>
<s t="2370" ac="252"> уже</s>
</p>
<p t="143770" d="3130" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="143780" d="5850" w="1">
<s ac="246">не</s>
<s t="150" ac="250"> на</s>
<s t="300" ac="218"> пушках</s>
<s t="750" ac="77"> а</s>
<s t="929" ac="201"> на</s>
<s t="1140" ac="252"> ножках</s>
<s t="1740" ac="208"> и</s>
<s t="2039" ac="215"> это</s>
<s t="2429" ac="107"> флиппин</s>
</p>
<p t="146890" d="2740" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="146900" d="5610" w="1">
<s ac="68">аиф</s>
<s t="330" ac="249"> в</s>
<s t="510" ac="237"> которой</s>
<s t="930" ac="249"> ты</s>
<s t="1050" ac="243"> точно</s>
<s t="1500" ac="140"> также</s>
<s t="2010" ac="251"> покупаешь</s>
</p>
<p t="149620" d="2890" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="149630" d="5370" w="1">
<s ac="245">ножики</s>
<s t="510" ac="141"> и</s>
<s t="750" ac="252"> при</s>
<s t="1020" ac="252"> помощи</s>
<s t="1380" ac="245"> той</s>
<s t="1740" ac="246"> же</s>
<s t="1829" ac="241"> гравитации</s>
</p>
<p t="152500" d="2500" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="152510" d="3809" w="1">
<s ac="236">стараешься</s>
<s t="900" ac="252"> в</s>
<s t="1020" ac="252"> разных</s>
<s t="1440" ac="218"> режимов</s>
<s t="1949" ac="252"> игры</s>
<s t="2130" ac="252"> набрать</s>
</p>
<p t="154990" d="1329" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="155000" d="3200" w="1">
<s ac="252">побольше</s>
<s t="360" ac="255"> очков</s>
</p>
<p t="156309" d="1891" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="156319" d="4920" w="1">
<s ac="160">опять</s>
<s t="451" ac="193"> таки</s>
<s t="631" ac="252"> здесь</s>
<s t="841" ac="214"> ничего</s>
<s t="1441" ac="252"> сложного</s>
</p>
<p t="158190" d="3049" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="158200" d="5950" w="1">
<s ac="162">разберешь</s>
<s t="1000" ac="71"> что</s>
<s t="1180" ac="255"> но</s>
<s t="1360" ac="136"> позалипать</s>
<s t="2050" ac="252"> когда</s>
<s t="2530" ac="242"> нечего</s>
</p>
<p t="161229" d="2921" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="161239" d="5011" w="1">
<s ac="252">делать</s>
<s t="91" ac="199"> очень</s>
<s t="991" ac="238"> даже</s>
<s t="1261" ac="252"> можно</s>
<s t="1651" ac="252"> и</s>
<s t="2011" ac="252"> дальше</s>
<s t="2401" ac="251"> я</s>
<s t="2701" ac="252"> в</s>
</p>
<p t="164140" d="2110" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="164150" d="4470" w="1">
<s ac="252">последнее</s>
<s t="510" ac="252"> время</s>
<s t="630" ac="252"> не</s>
<s t="960" ac="252"> плохо</s>
<s t="1320" ac="248"> так</s>
<s t="1619" ac="242"> залип</s>
<s t="2070" ac="252"> в</s>
</p>
<p t="166240" d="2380" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="166250" d="5070" w="1">
<s ac="166">одну</s>
<s t="360" ac="208"> онлайн</s>
<s t="780" ac="251"> игрушку</s>
<s t="1230" ac="252"> которая</s>
<s t="1709" ac="252"> называется</s>
<s t="2220" ac="201"> а</s>
</p>
<p t="168610" d="2710" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="168620" d="4020" w="1">
<s ac="193">raider</s>
<s t="630" ac="213"> и</s>
<s t="690" ac="252"> всем</s>
<s t="1140" ac="252"> кто</s>
<s t="1290" ac="252"> играл</s>
<s t="1860" ac="242"> в</s>
<s t="1950" ac="202"> классические</s>
</p>
<p t="171310" d="1330" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="171320" d="4110" w="1">
<s ac="236">фэнтези</s>
<s t="510" ac="0"> lpg</s>
</p>
<p t="172630" d="2800" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="172640" d="5730" w="1">
<s ac="218">игра</s>
<s t="330" ac="236"> по-любому</s>
<s t="900" ac="240"> зайдёт</s>
<s t="1230" ac="231"> в</s>
<s t="1770" ac="251"> поиске</s>
<s t="2190" ac="217"> старое</s>
<s t="2670" ac="205"> и</s>
</p>
<p t="175420" d="2950" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="175430" d="5910" w="1">
<s ac="236">можно</s>
<s t="420" ac="248"> найти</s>
<s t="720" ac="251"> как</s>
<s t="1110" ac="60"> great</s>
<s t="1559" ac="216"> shadow</s>
<s t="2010" ac="215"> legends</s>
<s t="2700" ac="60"> и</s>
</p>
<p t="178360" d="2980" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="178370" d="5010" w="1">
<s ac="247">это</s>
<s t="330" ac="252"> абсолютно</s>
<s t="1050" ac="252"> бесплатная</s>
<s t="1920" ac="252"> онлайн</s>
<s t="2430" ac="252"> игра</s>
<s t="2460" ac="248"> в</s>
</p>
<p t="181330" d="2050" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="181340" d="3810" w="1">
<s ac="252">которой</s>
<s t="330" ac="248"> вы</s>
<s t="480" ac="255"> прокачиваете</s>
<s t="1050" ac="250"> одного</s>
<s t="1740" ac="252"> или</s>
</p>
<p t="483740" d="2739" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="483750" d="4560" w="1">
<s ac="252">конечно</s>
<s t="180" ac="234"> же</s>
<s t="690" ac="252"> подписывайтесь</s>
<s t="1560" ac="252"> на</s>
<s t="1710" ac="252"> канал</s>
<s t="1919" ac="201"> и</s>
<s t="2430" ac="250"> как</s>
</p>
<p t="486469" d="1841" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="486479" d="4471" w="1">
<s ac="210">всегда</s>
<s t="211" ac="255"> посоветуют</s>
<s t="961" ac="210"> также</s>
<s t="1261" ac="242"> включить</s>
</p>
<p t="488300" d="2650" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="488310" d="4890" w="1">
<s ac="252">колокольчик</s>
<s t="530" ac="248"> уведомлений</s>
<s t="1530" ac="201"> вам</s>
<s t="1859" ac="198"> не</s>
<s t="1979" ac="195"> сложно</s>
<s t="2220" ac="207"> но</s>
</p>
<p t="490940" d="2260" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="490950" d="4200" w="1">
<s ac="252">так</s>
<s t="360" ac="248"> мои</s>
<s t="570" ac="242"> выпуски</s>
<s t="930" ac="240"> хоть</s>
<s t="1260" ac="252"> иногда</s>
<s t="1380" ac="93"> до</s>
<s t="1800" ac="252"> будут</s>
</p>
<p t="493190" d="1960" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="493200" d="5490" w="1">
<s ac="240">появляться</s>
<s t="480" ac="252"> у</s>
<s t="630" ac="252"> вас</s>
<s t="930" ac="252"> на</s>
<s t="1050" ac="252"> главной</s>
<s t="1410" ac="255"> странице</s>
</p>
<p t="495140" d="3550" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="495150" d="16760" w="1">
<s ac="249">youtube</s>
<s t="389" ac="210"> а</s>
<s t="660" ac="156"> еда</s>
<s t="1139" ac="255"> на</s>
<s t="1350" ac="244"> этом</s>
<s t="1769" ac="252"> пока</s>
<s t="2010" ac="221"> все</s>
<s t="2370" ac="238"> удачи</s>
</p>
<p t="498680" d="13230" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="498690" d="13469" w="1">[музыка]</p>
<p t="511900" d="259" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="511910" d="4909" w="1">
<s ac="215">а</s>
</p>
<p t="512149" d="4670" w="1" a="1"> </p>
<p t="512159" d="4660" w="1">[музыка]</p>
</body>
</timedtext>
```

В конечном итоге нужен массив, у которого значения - это содержимое тегов s (слова там), а ключи - это значения атрибута t этих же тегов s плюс значение атрибута t вышестоящего тега p. Причем у первых тегов s нет атрибута t => t=0.
Пример конечного массива после преобразования первых трёх (не пустых) тегов p из xml выше:

```
420  привет
900  пока
1230     я
1380     готовлю
1680     выпуск
2220     про

2490    один
2490+419     день
2490+630     из
2490+780     жизни
2490+810     программисты
2490+1710    где
2490+1920    все

4680    снимаю
4680+389     на
4680+480     камеру
4680+720     как
4680+990     и
4680+1199    обещал
4680+2010    я
4680+2310    решил
```

Comment: xpath как-то так //*/p/s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы смотрел в сторону [DomParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

Последнюю часть задания я не понял.

Что касается разбора документа XML, то вот пример кода:

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const dom = parser.parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml');
const sElements = [...dom.querySelectorAll('p > s')];
```

В `sElements` хранится список всех элементов `<s>`, которые находятся внутри элемента `<p>`. Дальше можно пройтись по списку и получить то, что Вам нужно.

Если нужен массив массивов:

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const dom = parser.parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml');
const result = [...dom.querySelectorAll('p > s')].map(element =>
  [Number(element.parentNode.getAttribute('t')) + Number(element.getAttribute('t')), element.textContent]
)
```

Если нужен объект:

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const dom = parser.parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml');
const result = [...dom.querySelectorAll('p > s')].map(element =>
  ({
    [Number(element.parentNode.getAttribute('t')) + Number(element.getAttribute('t'))]: element.textContent
  })
)
```